# Javascript: forEach on an inplace array often fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I often want to do something like this:

```
["string1", "string2"].forEach(function(str) { 
    // Handle string
})
```

This seems to work occasionally, but often (Chrome, at least) will throw

```
Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
```

Why is my inplace array "undefined"?

By contrast, this will work as expected:

```
var myStrings = ["string1", "string2"]
myStrings.forEach(function(str) {
    // Handle string
})
```

What gives?

**Edit**

Code example:

```
// This works:
var methods = {}
,   methodNames = ["move", "x", "y", "cx", "cy", "opacity", "attr", "fill", "stroke", "front", "after", "back", "dx", "dmove", "dy", "remove"]

methodNames.forEach(function(method) {
    methods[method] = { value: function() { return this.mainGroup[method].apply(this.mainGroup, arguments) }}
})

// This throws "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
methods = {}
["move", "x", "y", "cx", "cy", "opacity", "attr", "fill", "stroke", "front", "after", "back", "dx", "dmove", "dy", "remove"].forEach(function(method) {
    methods[method] = { value: function() { return this.mainGroup[method].apply(this.mainGroup, arguments) }}
})
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, forEach works fine for me in chrome.

Comment: Please provide an example code.

Comment: @Mr_Pouet - Code example provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lack of semicolon next to "methods = {}" induces an error.

```
// This throws "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
methods = {};  // <-- HERE
["move", "x", "y", "cx", "cy", "opacity", "attr", "fill", "stroke", "front", "after", "back", "dx", "dmove", "dy", "remove"].forEach(function(method) {
    methods[method] = { value: function() { return this.mainGroup[method].apply(this.mainGroup, arguments); }}
});
```

{} is equivalent to an empty Object. Hence if you do something such as {}['a'] it will evaluate to undefined and {}[] is invalid syntax.

Note that {}['a', 'b', 'c'] is valid since you could do this:

```
var a = {};
a['a', 'b'] = 1;  // a = {'a':1 , 'b':1}
```

Though not necessary, as a good practice, I would recommend putting semicolons whenever applicable.

Comment: Thanks! But why? Why isn't {}[] valid by itself?